# getting error when generating APK using progurd

Tags: android, proguard

i'm getting below error when enabling progurd. please assist
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't read [/root/AndroidStudioProjects/ChurchOfChristHymns/app/bin/classes] (No such file or directory)

i have tried to run gradlew assembleRelease, still not working

```
buld.gradle file look like this :
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.root.churchofchristhymns"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
}
```

my progurd-rules.txt looks like this :

```
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs
-outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
-libraryjars /usr/local/java/android-sdk/platforms/android-9/android.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this from

buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

to

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-  rules.txt'
        }
    }

Comment: now i'm getting below error after Error after modifying buldTypes:

(16, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'minifyEnabled()'!

Possible causes could be:  
  - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent (<a href="open_gradle_settings">Fix Gradle settings</a>)

  - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method (<a href="apply_gradle_plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a>)

  - or there is a mistake in a build script (<a href="goto_source">Goto source</a>)